# python groupby with two conditions and calculate the mean

Tags: python, group-by

I have one dataframe as below. I want to groupby this dataframe by two conditions (column 'date' and column 'price') and add one column to calculate the mean of "price2"(which has the same date and price). Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [20130101,20130101, 20130105, 20130105, 20130101, 20130108],
    'price': [25, 25, 23.5, 27, 40, 8],
     'price2':[23,56,45,67,33,2]
})
       date  output  price  price2
0  20130101    39.5   25.0      23
1  20130101    39.5   25.0      56
2  20130105    45.0   23.5      45
3  20130105    67.0   27.0      67
4  20130101    33.0   40.0      33
5  20130108     2.0    8.0       2
```

Comment: Can you include a dataframe of the expected output?

Comment: @U9-Forward I have inserted the expected output.

Comment: @timgeb I have inserted the expected output.

Comment: NPE and U9 both answered your query so you might select whichever suits your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.transform`:

```
newdf=df2.groupby(['date','price']).transform('mean')
```

Now:

```
print(newdf)
```

Is:

```
   price2
0    39.5
1    39.5
2    45.0
3    67.0
4    33.0
5     2.0
```

Now to get extra columns, do:

```
newdf.columns=['output']
newdf=pd.concat([newdf,df2],axis=1)
```

Then now:

```
print(newdf)
```

Is:

```
   output      date  price  price2
0    39.5  20130101   25.0      23
1    39.5  20130101   25.0      56
2    45.0  20130105   23.5      45
3    67.0  20130105   27.0      67
4    33.0  20130101   40.0      33
5     2.0  20130108    8.0       2
```

Then also add:

```
df2=df2.insert(1, 'output', newdf)
```

If wanted correct index for columns

Then now:

```
print(newdf)
```

Is:

```
       date  output  price  price2
0  20130101    39.5   25.0      23
1  20130101    39.5   25.0      56
2  20130105    45.0   23.5      45
3  20130105    67.0   27.0      67
4  20130101    33.0   40.0      33
5  20130108     2.0    8.0       2
```

Comment: Elegant and beginner friendly. +1

Comment: Consider `df2.insert(1, 'output', newdf)`.

Comment: @Shiv_90 Thank you, happy that it's good, , and easy (using `transform`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the groupby function of pandas:

```
grp = df2.groupby(['date', 'price']).agg('price2':'mean').rename(columns={'price2':'output'})
pd.merge(df2, grp, on=['date', 'price'])
```